# Does "device reset to factory settings" make data unrecoverable?

Tags: android, security

Regarding to the conclusion of University of Texas, [Information security report](https://wikis.utexas.edu/display/ISO/Google+Android+Hardening+Checklist#GoogleAndroidHardeningChecklist-8): The factory reset option provided in Android, does erase all data, but not securely - the data can be recovered by anyone with physical access to the device.  There is no native way to securely delete all user data.  Some third party applications available in the Android Marketplace can provide this functionality.

Does anybody know is data recoverable after reset? Any public proof of it or Util app which can do it?

If I am calling DevicePolicyManager.wipeData(flags) will user data stored on the internal/external storage be recoverable after that?

If device partition was encrypted, will wipeData() method destroy encryption key, so the data will be undecryptable 100%? 
Does anybody know exactly how wipeData() works or can point me to a proper reference?

Answer (score 3):

I have seen references to people using Recuva to recover data after doing a factory reset.  Apparently you need to mount the sd card via USB and then it's recovered like any other undelete process.  This makes sense as the SD in Android is formatted using FAT, which has always been easy to undelete.

Comment: Tried Recuva, it doesn't see tablet's (Motorola Xoom "3.2") neither external nor internal storage. There are still even more questions (updated).