# DevicePolicyManager wipeData whitepaper?

Tags: android, security

would anyone have links to how the wipeData operates for DevicePolicyManager?
Need to understand if it is cryptographically secure in that the data is no longer recoverable.

Comment: Asked the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749544/does-device-reset-to-factory-settings-makes-data-unrecoverable got closed